# Google Geocoder Asynchronous Issue

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, google-geocoder

I believe that I have having a timing issue with geocoder results. See a snippet of code below.

I am basically performing a geocode and getting the result. I then pass the result to a server side method via the jQuery AJAX call. Finally the result of the method returns a JSON object. Based on the result I may or may not perform a second geocode. This is where the problem lies.

You can see I have a variable `hasResult` defaulted to false, and is toggled to true when a valid result has been determined. In all cases this works perfect, except when the need for a second geocode occurs. The geocode happens successfully and the code executes, but the final `hasResult` check still returns false. How can this be?

```
var hasResult = false;            
geocoder.geocode({ "address": address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "URL",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: results
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Valid) {
                            hasResult = false;
                            //Some other code, works perfect                            
                        } else {
                            geocoder.geocode({ "address": result.ValidRequest }, function (resultsNew, statusNew) {
                                if (statusNew == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    hasResult = false; 
                                    //Some other code, works perfect
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

if (hasResult == true) {
    alert('Success');
} else {
    alert('Fail');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you check the value of `hasResult` *before* you get the results from the server. This happens, because the request is asynchrounous. You should use callbacks instead.

**Edit:**

Try this (this is only a mockup and is not tested, change it to improve readability, pass `successOrFailure` as a parameter/callback etc.):

```
var hasResult = false;            

var successOrFailure = function(hasResult){
    if (hasResult == true) {
        alert('Success');
    } else {
        alert('Fail');
    }
};

geocoder.geocode({ "address": address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "URL",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: results
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Valid) {
                            hasResult = false;
                            successOrFailure(hasResult);
                            //Some other code, works perfect                            
                        } else {
                            geocoder.geocode({ "address": result.ValidRequest }, function (resultsNew, statusNew) {
                                if (statusNew == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    hasResult = false;
                                    successOrFailure(hasResult); 
                                    //Some other code, works perfect
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that the geocoder gets called, but the script continues through to the conditional statement and the rest will complete. Makes sense, can you provide a mock up of what you propose?

Comment: @Dusting I have added some raw example to show you how this can be made. 'Callback' function(actually `successOrFailure` function) is executed after you know whether you failed or succeeded. Adapt it to your needs. Does it work for you?

Comment: Great :) Happy I was helpful.